# Django - How to return tagged content from two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a legacy code that uses django basic apps. The basic blog app has tag results page.

I would like to know how can I extend this method to return tagged content from two models. The Post model and some other model.

```
def tag_detail(request, slug, template_name='blog/tag_detail.html', **kwargs):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, name__iexact=slug)

    return list_detail.object_list(
        request,
        queryset=Post.objects.filter(tags__name__iexact=slug, status=2),
        extra_context={'tag': tag},
        template_name=template_name,
        **kwargs
    )
```

**EDIT**

Here is what I ended up doing

```
quertsetA = A.objects.filter(tags__name__iexact=slug, status=2)
querysetB = B.objects.filter(tags__name__iexact=slug, status=2)

result_list = list(chain(quertsetA, querysetB))
```

This works in the python shell but only quertsetA's values are being passed to the template.

Here is the relevant part of the view

```
return list_detail.object_list(
    request,
    queryset=result_list,
    template_name=template_name,
    **kwargs
)
```

And template

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the querysets to lists then you can just concatenate them

```
quertsetA = [p for p in Post.objects.filter(tags_name_iexact=slug, status=2)]
querysetB = [o for o in Other.objects.filter(tags_name_iexact=slug...)]
queryset = querysetA+querysetB
```

Comment: This definitely helped me to get the two queries merged. I added my solution. However, now I have a problem to display the merged query in the template.